# full text search not working for varchar in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have designed a myisam table for full text search purpose.

[image: small part of table]

I have define full text for `customer_code` column. `customer_code` is `varchar(20)`. It only search for "1234" and "0011" but not for "123" and "456".

My sql query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_customer 
WHERE MATCH(tbl_customer.customer_code) AGAINST('123')
```

Do i have to define some more for it?

Comment: which Operating System you are in ?

Comment: Now i am using windows 7 ultimate(32 bit).

Comment: yes it is wamp server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not work because of the word length being specified on **ft_min_word_len**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

So in debian/ubuntu its usually **/etc/mysql/my.cnf**

You need to set the min length there. In your case I suppose its 4 so you need to set it less than that.

Make sure after resetting the word length to restart the mysql. In addition you may need to drop the indexes and rebuilt or repair the table.

More over there are different way you can use wild card on full text search. Check the following this might help you.

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?107,113504,113504

In WAMP you can find the configuration file on WAMP wizard or in

```
\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql{version}\my.ini
```